# How to make sure code has no data races in Go?

Tags: go, race-condition, goroutine

I'm writing a microservice that calls other microservices, for data that rarely updates (once in a day or once in a month). So I decided to create cache, and implemented this interface:

```
type StringCache interface {
    Get(string) (string, bool)
    Put(string, string)
}
```

internally it's just `map[string]cacheItem`, where

```
type cacheItem struct {
    data      string
    expire_at time.Time
}
```

My coworker says that it's unsafe, and I need add mutex locks in my methods, because it will be used in parallel by different instances of http handler functions. I have a test for it, but it detects no data races, because it uses cache in one goroutine:

```
func TestStringCache(t *testing.T) {
    testDuration := time.Millisecond * 10
    cache := NewStringCache(testDuration / 2)

    cache.Put("here", "this")

    // Value put in cache should be in cache
    res, ok := cache.Get("here")
    assert.Equal(t, res, "this")
    assert.True(t, ok)

    // Values put in cache will eventually expire
    time.Sleep(testDuration)

    res, ok = cache.Get("here")
    assert.Equal(t, res, "")
    assert.False(t, ok)
}
```

So, my question is: how to rewrite this test that it detects data race (if it is present) when running with `go test -race`?

Comment: Add a test that does a bunch of gets & puts in separate goroutines? The asserts don't particularly matter if you're just looking to exercise parallelism and use the race detector.

Comment: You need to stress your code under concurrent operations, how you need to do so depends heavily on the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing first, the data race detector in Go is not some sort of formal prover which uses static code analysis but is rather a dynamic tool which instruments the *compiled* code in a special way to try to detect data races at runtime.
What this means is that if the race detector is lucky and it spots a data race, you ought to be sure there *is* a data race at the reported spot. But this also means that if the actual program flow did not make certain existing data race condition *happen,* the race detector won't spot and report it.
In oher words, the race detector does not have false positives but it is merely a best-effort tool.

So, in order to write race-free code you really have to rethink your approach.
It's best to start with [this classic essay on the topic](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WAT22FtFdMt43i3O8YrnlQTNTzZ3IoJBtu3P2DNRytg/view) written by the author of the Go race detector, and once you have absorbed that there is no benign data races, you basically just train yourself to think about concurrently running theads of execution accessing your data each time you're architecting the data and the algorithms to manipulate it.

For instance, you know (at least you *should* know if you have read the docs) that each incoming request to an HTTP server implemented using `net/http` is handled by a separate goroutine.
This means, that if you have a central (shared) data structure such as a cache which is to be accessed by the code which processes client requests, you *do* have multiple goroutines potentially accessing that shared data concurrently.

Now if you have another goroutine which *updates* that data, you do have a potential for a classic data race: while one goroutine is updating the data, another may read it.

As to the question at hand, two things:

First, *Never ever* use timers to test stuff. This does not work.

Second, for such a simple case as yours, using merely two goroutines completely suffices:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "time"
)

type cacheItem struct {
    data      string
    expire_at time.Time
}

type stringCache struct {
    m   map[string]cacheItem
    exp time.Duration
}

func (sc *stringCache) Get(key string) (string, bool) {
    if item, ok := sc.m[key]; !ok {
        return "", false
    } else {
        return item.data, true
    }
}

func (sc *stringCache) Put(key, data string) {
    sc.m[key] = cacheItem{
        data:      data,
        expire_at: time.Now().Add(sc.exp),
    }
}

func NewStringCache(d time.Duration) *stringCache {
    return &stringCache{
        m:   make(map[string]cacheItem),
        exp: d,
    }
}

func TestStringCache(t *testing.T) {
    cache := NewStringCache(time.Minute)

    ch := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        cache.Put("here", "this")
        close(ch)
    }()

    _, _ = cache.Get("here")

    <-ch
}
```

Save this as `sc_test.go` and then

```
tmp$ go test -race -c -o sc_test ./sc_test.go 
tmp$ ./sc_test 
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c00009e270 by goroutine 8:
  runtime.mapassign_faststr()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/runtime/map_faststr.go:202 +0x0
  command-line-arguments.(*stringCache).Put()
      /home/kostix/tmp/sc_test.go:27 +0x144
  command-line-arguments.TestStringCache.func1()
      /home/kostix/tmp/sc_test.go:46 +0x62

Previous read at 0x00c00009e270 by goroutine 7:
  runtime.mapaccess2_faststr()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/runtime/map_faststr.go:107 +0x0
  command-line-arguments.TestStringCache()
      /home/kostix/tmp/sc_test.go:19 +0x125
  testing.tRunner()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0x199

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  command-line-arguments.TestStringCache()
      /home/kostix/tmp/sc_test.go:45 +0xe4
  testing.tRunner()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0x199

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  testing.(*T).Run()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:960 +0x651
  testing.runTests.func1()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:1202 +0xa6
  testing.tRunner()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0x199
  testing.runTests()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:1200 +0x521
  testing.(*M).Run()
      /home/kostix/devel/golang-1.13.6/src/testing/testing.go:1117 +0x2ff
  main.main()
      _testmain.go:44 +0x223
==================
--- FAIL: TestStringCache (0.00s)
    testing.go:853: race detected during execution of test
FAIL
```

Comment: Note that your case appears to be really trivial. In non-trivial case, you basically need to to what @JimB said: have a test which uses _multiple_ goroutines all hammering the data they share. The trick is to have them employ different _pacing_ of their work sequence—for instance, one goroutine pefrorms its operation each N nanoseconds while another one—each 1.5×N nanoseconds. Ideally, have changed pacings (the `math/rand` package may help). What operations to do also can be randomized, etc.

Comment: …but all-in-all, _do not rely on such tests as *testifying* there are no data races._

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I get it, tests only show there are bugs, they do not show there are no bugs. :) 

While I'm diving into article you linked, additional question. You say: "Never ever use timers to test stuff". How then you will implement pacing you mention in your first comment? And how to check that cache items actually expire?

Comment: Ah, I really meant that you should never use timers for "poor-man's synchronization". Sure, when you're trying to write a test which is effectively trying to fuzz some subsystem, you usually have to resort to using timers precisely for the purposes of pacing.

Comment: As to testing expiration, this is actually a different topic completely, and a sad one: ideally, you have to write your code using an abstracted _something_ which implements time and then mock that something in tests. 3rd-party packages to do that do exist. Unfortunately, certain bits of the standard library rely on real `time.Time`, as do many if not most 3rd-party packages, so sometimes you simpy have no way to properly mock time in your tests.

Comment: JFTR, here at my $dayjob, we've implemented [`github.com/LopatkinEvgeniy/clock`](https://github.com/LopatkinEvgeniy/clock) because the other libs were lacking in one way or another at the time. YMMV, of course, but you could use that as a starting point.